# Azure Service for millions of datasets a month

Tags: azure

I´m looking for an **Azure service** that allows me to **log ~200 million datasets a month**. These are tracking datasets, so writing has to be fast.

The data will be read once or twice a day to cumulate the tracked data.

Does anyone know an Azure Service which makes sense for that?

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Data lake Service in Azure Seems to be a good option for your case

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details about the kind of "dataset". It´s a flat file with 100 records? Or, some million records? 
How often is it going to be sent to the system, some dozend each minute, or 10 million at the end of the day?

With these infos, if you know something about AWS, you can find an equivalent service on azure here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/aws-professional/services

If you are going to ingest a lot of request (like tracking events, or anything like) and want to summarize it by some time span, you can do some tests with IoT suite:
https://azure.microsoft.com/suites/iot-suite/

Comment: I have to store Tracking information. At the moment they are logged in a relational DBMS which is really hard to query with that many datasets. So writting has to be fast, reading happens one or two times a day when the KPI´s are calculated.